# How to Instantiate Connection between Student Class and my LinkedList<E>. Wont grab E.getElement()

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm working on creating my own LinkedList. My L.L. worked 100% when running simple I/O from command line, but now I have to implement it into my Student class. It adds a Student, displays a student, won't remove Student @ Node, in-fact, it won't even read THE ONLY student in the list! All BlueJ tells me is this:

> Error(s) found in class

It's some kind of connection logic and for two days I have tried everything I can think of.
Here is my Student, removeStudent(), Class Node, and LinkedList

```
public class Node
{
  private Student item;
  private Node node;
  private int thisIdx;  
  private String fullName,firstName,lastName,gender,major,netId;
  private int uin,age;
  private double gpa;

  public Node()
  {
    this(null,null);
  }
  public Node(Student stu,Node node)
  {
    this.item = stu;
    this.setNext(node);
    thisIdx = totalCount() - 1;
    this.setNodeIndex(thisIdx);
  }

  public int getIndex()
  {
    return this.thisIdx;
  }
  public void setNodeIndex(int idx)
  {
    thisIdx = idx;
  }
  public void setNext(Node n1)
  {
    node = n1;
  }
  public Node getNext()
  {
    return node;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return ( this == null);
  }
  public Student display()
  {
    return this.item;
  }
  public void setItem(Links data)
  {
    this.item  = data;
  }
  public Student getItem()
  {
    return item;
  }
}

public class Links<E>
{
    private Node start,tail,next;
    private int size=0;  private int idx;  private String item;
    private Student student;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MyLList
     */
    public Links()
    {
        start = new Node();
    }
    public void addLink(E object)
    {
        tail = start;
        start = new Node(object,tail);
        size++;
    }
    public int totalCount()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public Node get(Node node)
    {
        return node;

    }
    public void set(Node node)
    {
        node.setNext(node.getNext());
    }
    public String emptyMessage()
    {
        String message = "Your student is not in the student files.\n\n";
        return message;
    }
    public Node getStart()
    {
        Node curr = start;
        return curr;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        Node start = new Node();
        size = 0;
    }
    public void removeLink(Node node) throws NullPointerException
    {
        try{
            Node del,curr,next,prev;
            prev = start;   curr = start;
            while ( curr != node )
            {
                if ( curr.getNext() == null)
                {
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                }else
                {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr.getNext();
                }
            }
            if ( curr == start)
            {
                start = start.getNext();
            }else
            {
                prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }

        }catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            Lab_12.viewer.append("Breaking in Links" + "\n\n");
        }
    }
    public void sort()
    {
        Node curr,next,temp,prev;
        prev = start;
        curr = start;
        next = start.getNext();
        int move;
        Student[] copyToThis = new Student[this.size];
        if (this.totalCount() > 1)
        {
            //copy contents of linked list to array
            for (int i=0; i < this.totalCount(); i++)
            {
                if ( !curr.isEmpty() )
                {
                    Student copyItem = curr.getItem();
                    copyToThis[i] = copyItem;
                    prev = curr;
                    if ( curr.getNext() != null)
                    {
                        curr = curr.getNext();
                    }else
                    {
                        prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
                    }
                }
                for (int k=0; k < copyToThis.length-1;k++)
                {
                    int tempIdx = k;
                    if ( copyToThis[k] == null )
                    {
                        copyToThis[tempIdx] = copyToThis[k];
                        while ( k < copyToThis.length-1 )
                        {
                            copyToThis[k] = copyToThis[k+1];
                            copyToThis[k+1] = copyToThis[tempIdx];
                            tempIdx = k;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //sort array in reverse order ----->  LinkedList is FIFO structure
            for (int i =0; i < copyToThis.length; i++)
            {
                Student first = copyToThis[i];
                Student tempObject = copyToThis[i];
                int tempIndex = i;
                for (int k=i; k < copyToThis.length; k++)
                {
                    if (copyToThis[k] != null)
                    {
                        move = copyToThis[k].getFullName().compareToIgnoreCase(first.getFullName());
                        if (move > 0)
                        {
                            first = copyToThis[k];
                            tempIndex = k;
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (first == null )
                {
                    break;
                }else
                {
                    move = first.getFullName().compareToIgnoreCase(tempObject.getFullName());
                    if (move > 0 )
                    {
                        copyToThis[i] = first;
                        copyToThis[tempIndex] = tempObject;
                        tempIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            //clear list before setting in alphabetical order -----> if not cleared, list will append not replace
            this.clear();
            for (int i=0; i < copyToThis.length; i++)
            {
                if ( copyToThis[i] != null)
                {
                    this.addLink(copyToThis[i]);
                }

            }
        }
        //test print of array
        /*for (int i=0; i < copyToThis.length; i++)
        {
            Lab_12.viewer.append(i + ") " + copyToThis[i]);
        }*/
    }
    public String displayFirst()
    {
        Node first = start;
        String showFirst = first.getItem().toString();
        return showFirst;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        String showThisView;
        Node prev,curr,next;
        prev = start;   curr = prev; next = start.getNext();
        for (int i=0; i < this.totalCount();i++)
        {
            if (!curr.isEmpty())
            {
                showThisView = curr.getItem().toString();
                Lab_12.viewer.append(showThisView + "\n\n");
            }else
            {
                prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
                curr = curr.getNext();
                next = next.getNext();
            }
            prev = next;
            curr = prev;
            if (prev.getNext() != null)
            {
                next = prev.getNext();
            }else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public String search(String data) throws NullPointerException
    {
        try{
            Node p = start;
            while(p!=null)
            {
                if ( !p.getItem().equals(data) )
                {
                    p = p.getNext();
                }else
                {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            System.out.println("Your item is not in the list\n");
        }
    }
}






    public void removeStudent(Links<Student> studentLinks1) 
{
    try     
    {
            String toRemove;
            int choice;
            int counter =0; 
            toRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the student last name to be removed:");
            String find;
            int uin;
            for (Node i=studentLinks1.getStart(); i.getNext() != null; i.setNext(i.getNext()) )
            {
                 if ( studentLinks1.get(i).getFullName().equalsIgnoreCase(toRemove) )
                 {
                     counter++;
                 }
            }

            if (counter > 1)  
               {
                   viewer.append("You have more than one student with the last name, " + toRemove + ".\n\n");
                   viewer.append("Students with last name: " + toRemove + "\n\n");
                   /*
                    * create array to hold current matching indexes;
                    */

                   for (Node i=studentLinks1.getStart(); i.getNext() !=null; i.setNext(i.getNext()))
                   {
                      find = studentLinks1.get(i).getLastName().toString();
                      if ( studentLinks1.get(i).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(toRemove) )
                      {
                         uin = studentLinks1.get(i).getUin();
                         viewer.append("Name: " + studentLinks1.get(i).getFullName().toString() +
                                         "\n\tUIN: " + uin + "\n\n");
                      }
                   }

                   /*
                    * Get user input for student removal & remove student
                    */

                       int match = 0;
                       choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the UIN of the student you wish to remove: "));
                       for (Node i=studentLinks1.getStart(); i.getNext() !=null ; i.setNext(i.getNext()))
                       {
                           uin = studentLinks1.get(i).getUin();
                           if ( choice != uin)
                           {
                               match++;
                           }
                           if (match == Links.totalCount() )
                           {
                               throw new InputMismatchException();
                           }
                       }
                       for (Node i=studentLinks1.getStart(); i.getNext() != null; i.setNext(i.getNext()))
                       {
                           if ( studentLinks1.get(i).getUin() == choice ) 
                           {
                               String name = studentLinks1.get(i).getFullName().toString();
                               viewer.append(name + " " + " has been removed from the student file." + "\n\n");
                               studentLinks1.removeLink(i);
                               Student.removeStudent();

                               Student.getStudentCount();
                           }
                       }
                       viewer.append("There is " + Student.getStudentCount() + " student(s) in your student file." + "\n\n");
                       if ( counter == 1)
                       {
                           for (Node i=studentLinks1.getStart(); i.getNext() != null; i.setNext(i.getNext()))
                           {
                               if ( studentLinks1.get(i) != null && studentLinks1.get(i).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(toRemove) )
                               {
                                   String firstName = studentLinks1.get(i).getFirstName().toString();
                                   String lastName = studentLinks1.get(i).getLastName().toString();
                                   viewer.append(firstName + " " + lastName + " has been removed from the student file." + "\n\n");
                                   studentLinks1.removeLink(i);
                                   Student.removeStudent();
                               }
                           }

                           viewer.append("There is " + Student.getStudentCount() + " student(s) in your student file." + "\n\n");
                      }else
                      {
                           viewer.append(studentLinks1.emptyMessage());
                      }
            }  
    }catch (InputMismatchException ime )
    {
        viewer.append("You entered an incorrect student id.\nPlease re-enter the student id.");
        throw ime;
    }
}
```

As you can see in my `removeStudent()`, I have formatted the for loops to iterate through the L.L. with the nodes themselves. If in LL class, I can perform `node.getElement()` with results, then why will that not work in my main in Student? I have tried

```
studentLinks1.get(I).getItem().getElement();  
studentLinks1.get(i.getElement())
```

I am seriously at a loss with this one. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: *Error(s) found in class* So what are the errors - they need to be fixed

Comment: Near as I can tell, `removeStudent` is going to go into an infinite loop if the is more than one Student in the given list.

Comment: You added the `removeStudent()` method outside of the `Links` class (after the closing brace that ends the class). Why is Links generic if it only deals with students? Why aren't the properties of students like first and last name all inside the Student class? Why does a Student have a count of students? Isn't each one just one student?

Comment: Side note regarding `this.setNext(node);` - prefixing a method call with `this.` is utterly redundant.